# Error use sweetaleet2 in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ubuntu, sweetalert2

I install sweetalert2 in angular4 with:

> npm install --save sweetalert2

In windows is work and i work with swal but in ubuntu I have this error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/c/Users/moham/public_html/oribiky-dashboard/node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.j
>   s'

I apply commande line for install sweetalert2 but is not working and stop in install in 92%

Comment: Do you get an error when the command install fails? The first thought that always comes to mind with Linux is permissions on the target directories.

Comment: try to npm uninstall sweetalert2 then npm install again

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. It worked for me !

```
npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.24
```